# Three.js WebGl resize object weird behavior

Tags: javascript, animation, position, three.js, webgl

I had a code that was working fine but it stopped working when i enabled WebGL.
In general I had a function that is resizing my object every frameRate.

```
function animate(){

     window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     s.setPosition(s.x - 1, s.y - 1, 0);
}

s.prototype.setPosition = function(x, y, z) {

this.x = x; 
this.y = y; 
this.z = z; 

this.squareMesh.geometry.vertices[0].set( x,  y, z);
this.squareMesh.geometry.vertices[1].set( x + this.w - 1, y, z);
this.squareMesh.geometry.vertices[2].set( x + this.w - 1, y - this.h + 1, z);
this.squareMesh.geometry.vertices[3].set( x,  y -  this.h + 1, z);
 }
```

This was working fine, untill I enabled WebGl. When enabled nothing happens to the object, seems like values are not updated.

When I use build in function like

`obj.position.x = s.x +1` it works.

but this causes other problems like 0 0 0 position for every object. I refer to that problem here : [Three.js, WebGl Object position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471868/three-js-webgl-object-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

This should tell Three.js that the vertices are changed and need a refresh:

`this.squareMesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;`